# What type of wallet support French seed-phrases?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed, passphrase, bip38

been struggling to find wallet to restore it as it seems most wallets support only English.

Answer (score 1):

BIP39 (the specification for how seeds can be encoded into phrases) specified a number of word lists beside English but it has been widely considered a bad idea to use them. Words can be ambiguous between languages, and many use encodings which are not guaranteed to be consistent or supported on every system. Little software ever supported any language other than English, and as a result none is likely to add it in the future to maintain compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I am Blockchain guy and And retrieve lost wallet.
But you can do this yourself you can use https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ Select French and paste 12/24 words. It will extract all address with Private Key ️